# Best algorithm to calculate the condition number of a matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, soft-question, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

The condition number of a matrix $A$ is $\kappa(A)=\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|$.

What is the best algorithm to calculate it?

Comment: context? Programming language? Or do you want a theoretic algorithm?

Comment: @Exodd I want to know an algotirhm.